# Autofac modules with their own dependencies

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm struggling with how to organize my Autofac component registrations in modules given that some of the modules themselves have dependencies.

I've implemented an abstraction of configuration data (*i.e.* web.config) in an interface:

```
interface IConfigurationProvider
{
    T GetSection<T>(string sectionName)
        where T : System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection;
}
```

along with implementations for ASP.NET (`WebConfigurationProvider`) and "desktop" applications (`ExeConfigurationProvider`).

Some of my autofac modules then require an `IConfigurationProvider` as a constructor parameter, but some don't:

```
class DependentModule : Module
{
    public DependentModule(IConfigurationProvider config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var configSection = _config.GetSection<CustomConfigSection>("customSection");
        builder.RegisterType(configSection.TypeFromConfig);
    }

    private readonly IConfigurationProvider _config;
}

class IndependentModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(/* other stuff not based on configuration */);
    }
}
```

Since the `RegisterType()` extension method doesn't accept a registration delegate (`Func<IComponentContext, T>`), like `Register()` does, I can't register the `IConfigurationProvider` up-front and then resolve it when I go to register the type specified in the configuration, something like:

```
// this would be nice...
builder.RegisterType(c => c.Resolve<IConfigurationProvider>().GetSection<CustomConfigSection>("sectionName").TypeFromConfig);
```

This means that I need to be able to register modules **with and without** a dependency on `IConfigurationProvider`.

It's obvious how to manually instantiate each module and register it:

```
IConfigurationProvider configProvider = ...;
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new DependentModule(configProvider));
builder.RegisterModule(new IndependentModule());
using (var container = builder.Build())
{
    ...
}
```

But I don't want to manually instantiate my modules - I want to scan assemblies for modules and register them automatically (as discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018831/autofac-module-scanning-for-various-applications)).  So I have to use reflection to scan the assembly for `IModule` types, and use `Activator.CreateInstance` to make registerable instances.  But how do I know whether or not to pass an `IConfigurationProvider` as a constructor parameter.  And what happens when other modules have additional or different dependencies?

There's got to be a more straightforward way of accomplishing the basic task: register a type specified in some configuration provided via an interface, right?  So how do I do that?

Comment: Did you solve this in the end? I have very similar case, but my dependency is having another dependency in its turn (I want to get config from db, so I have a IConfigProvider dependent on IRepoConfig)

Comment: @Learner, I originally implemented something using a combination of Autofac and MEF modeled after Jim Bolla's answer below, but it was horrendously complex and I removed it before too long. I don't have dependent modules any longer: since my primary use case was selection based on a `Type`, I've since taken the approach of *registering* **all** the candidates, then *resolving* based on the property coming from the `ConfigurationSection`. I can send you sample code if you'd like.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I don't think I could use ConfigurationSection / xml in my case.

Comment: This can be helpful: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57257634/1453867

Answer (score 7):

You could do something like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Core;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Yo_dawg
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class I_heard_you_like_containers
    {
        [Test]
        public void So_we_built_a_container_to_build_your_container()
        {
            var modules = GetModules();
            Assert.That(modules.Length, Is.EqualTo(4));

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            foreach (var module in modules)
                builder.RegisterModule(module);

            var container = builder.Build();
        }

        private IModule[] GetModules()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            var configurationProvider = new ConfigurationProvider();
            builder.RegisterInstance(configurationProvider).AsImplementedInterfaces().ExternallyOwned();

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(GetType().Assembly)
                .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo<IModule>())
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();

            using (var container = builder.Build())
                return container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IModule>>().ToArray();
        }
    }

    public class ModuleA : Module
    {
        public ModuleA(IConfigurationProvider config)
        {
        }
    }

    public class ModuleB : Module
    {
        public ModuleB(IConfigurationProvider config)
        {
        }
    }

    public class ModuleC : Module
    {
    }

    public class ModuleD : Module
    {
    }


    public interface IConfigurationProvider
    {
    }

    public class ConfigurationProvider : IConfigurationProvider
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I pursued a similar strategy, but didn't like certain aspects of it.  I'll have to revisit this approach.

Answer (score 2):

For this scenario, Autofac's own XML configuration seems to cover the scenarios you're targeting. Adding a new `IConfigurationProvider` mechanism seems like reinventing this functionality already provided by the container. The basics are documented at: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/XmlConfiguration. The configuration syntax has in-built support for modules.

There's a nice alternative by Paul Stovell that allows modules to be registered in code yet receive parameters from config - see: http://www.paulstovell.com/convention-configuration. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't understand how expressing my Autofac configuration in XML helps me out in this scenario.  Perhaps because I slightly messed up the code in my question, and which I just edited to better express the idea that I'm trying to work with custom SectionHandler types.